# Apache Rewrite Rule, With or Without Slash

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, rule

How can I get Apache to rewrite all URLs such as:

mydomain.com/index.php?name=about-me

to work with EITHER

mydomain.com/about-me

or

mydomain.com/about-me/

If the URL is mydomain.com/about-me, mydomain.com/index.php?name=about-me should load.

Also, if the URL is mydomain.com/about-me/, mydomain.com/index.php?name=about-me should load as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_rewrite include in your .htaccess file this rule to rewrite name=whatever to whatever/

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$     index.php?name=$1  [NC,L]
```

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work.
Also, the rule shouldn't limit my URLs to only alphabetic characters.

Comment: this rule only accept alphabetic plus - characters. Check that apache's mod_rewrite is working correctly

Comment: your should enable mod_rewrite RewriteEngine On and set the base url of your webserver RewriteBase /. Check a mod_rewrite tutorial.

Comment: It does not work. Yes, I've used .htaccess before and have mod_rewrite enabled and RewriteEngine. mydomain.com/index.html?name=whatever should work as mydomain.com/whatever.

Comment: sorry I missunderstood the question, the rule should be reversed. editing the answer

Comment: Wrong again. Well, I found the answer after searching Google. It's: RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [L] notice the placement of the slash, VERY important.

Comment: in your question you wrote - and not _ so the dash is correct. and the slash at the beginning i think is because your rewrite base doesn't end with the /, also you don't need A-Z when using [NC] that means non case sensitive. My answer was correct except for the beginning slash, the one I cannot imagine if you don't post your rewrite base value in the answer. And you'll need to add the ending / if you wan't to catch urls like mydomain.com/about-me/